# Populating dropdown list with couple words from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when populating drop-down list from MySQL with fields that contain two or more words.

For instance, when I populate the drop-down with names it says John Smith, but when I enter data in another table from that drop-down, only John is stored in the database without Smith.

What could be the problem?

Here's the code:

```
<td>
  <select name="opstina">
    <option value=></option>
    <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM opstine");
        while($podaci = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<option value= {$podaci['naziv']}>{$podaci['naziv']}</option>";
        }
    ?>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without any code.

Comment: Need to see what [you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Table from which I load data into dropdown is simple just having ID and Name columns. For single words everything works perfectly, but when there are multiple words only first one is entered into second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you need to quote your values ...

```
<td>
    <select name="opstina"> 
    <option value=""></option> 
    <?php 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM opstine"); 
        while($podaci = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
            echo '<option value="' . $podaci['naziv'] . '">' . $podaci['naziv'] . '</option>'; 
        }
    ?> 
    </select>
</td>
```

Otherwise it ends up being `<option value=John Smith>` in the HTML and only John would be assigned to the value ... you want it to be `<option value="John Smith">` ...

Comment: Yep, it did the trick, I forgot to quote. Thanks a lot @dleiftah!